# Changing GMSMarker icon doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, gmsmapview

I'm trying to change `GMSMarker` icon with `Moa` but marker is still showing default icon. This is my code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationmanager.delegate = self
        let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if(authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse || authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways) {
            locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()
            MapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            MapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        } else {
            locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        MapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 32.4279, longitude: 53.6880, zoom: 5)
        MapView.delegate = self
        prepareMapMarkers()
    }        
    func prepareMapMarkers(){
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(malls[0].lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(malls[0].long)))
        marker.map = MapView
        moa.onSuccess = { image in
            print(image)
            marker.icon = image.images?[0]
            return image
        }
        moa.url = "http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"
    }
```

console

```
<UIImage: 0x60000009e050>, {600, 400}
```

That image is just for test. Why it's not working?

Comment: Can you post all your code section, in order to see whats is happening?

Comment: question edited @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 3):

Try this! It worked for me

```
let pin = UIImage(named: "maps_icon_location")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
                                marker.icon = pin
```

Comment: but I want to load it with `Moa` library

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to change the image of a marker after it is added. I am not sure if Google Maps SDK supports this, but it is not a good idea. Instead, download you photo, then create the marker and add it to the map:

```
moa.onSuccess = { image in
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(malls[0].lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(malls[0].long)))
    marker.icon = image.images?[0]
    marker.map = self.MapView
}
moa.url = "http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does image.images?[0] return anything?

Comment: yes it returns same thing as I mentioned in my question